# Trying to create a dataframe on R from a directory that contains files of different types of files i.e. png, tif, rds

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, directory

As the question states, I am trying to make a data frame on R from a directory that has different types of files. I have tried this code:

```
setwd("/working/directory/here")

file_list <- list.files()



# Creating the dataset for all the files in file_list.

for (file in file_list) {
  
  # if the merged dataset does not exist, create it.
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
  }
  
  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it.
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
    dataset <- rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }
  
}
```

But end up receiving several different errors and am not sure how to go about it:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
3: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
5: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
7: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
8: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
9: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

Code when using rbindlist:

```
setwd("/srv/shiny-server/magneto/Storage/1880")

file_list_1880 <- list.files()

all_data <- rbindlist(lapply(file_list_1880, fread), fill = TRUE)
all_data
```

Error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  embedded nul in string: '\xf5\xfd\x9e\x9a\xc0:\xea~\xa1\u07fcV\xfd\xbd\xe4s\xf9\x99\U02e6aead\xdfC\xb6y\x97\xfa\xbd\xa6$g\xa9\xef۩\xf7\xaf>g\xdf\023\xe0\f\xfa:\0p\x97\xfaߛw\xed+\xf5\xf3?\xfb^\xf5sJ99\001\xe0\021\xe6\r\0\0\x85\xfaw\023\xfb-\xafP\xdf\xe7\xa9'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Previous fread() session was not cleaned up properly. Cleaned up ok at the beginning of this fread() call.
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Detected 3 column names but the data has 2 columns. Filling rows automatically. Set fill=TRUE explicitly to avoid this warning.
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Stopped early on line 26. Expected 3 fields but found 4. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <      >>
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Detected 3 column names but the data has 5 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 2 extra default column names at the end.
```

Comment: This issue may be related to your file delimiter.  Usually, `fread` picks up automatically.  What is your delimiter and I see some embeded null issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by delimiter exactly. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It is whethere your files have `,` or `\t` separated.  In addition, there is some embeeded null error you are getting.  SO, it must be some encoding issues

Comment: The files are just images. Like either .tif, .png, or .rds, so I'm not sure if they contain either of those things. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Ohh, so it is not just just `.csv`.  I was thinking that it is .csv.  If it is .rds you may need `readRDS

Comment: I'm basically trying to make it into a .csv by making it into a dataset first. But yeah, there are different file types such as the ones I said before. Would you be willing to edit the way you did it before to potentially accommodate that? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: if these are image files, etc, you may need different packages.  I am not sure what your objective with rbinding different types of file input

Comment: That was just what I found to do online, but clearly it's not working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your list of files, `lapply` over it and later `dplyr::bind_rows` to form one, large dataframe.

Here is a small example

```
data_list = lapply(file_list, function(x) {
  read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
})

all_data = dplyr::bind_rows(data_list)
```

Comment: Where should I use lapply?

Comment: You can see from my example code where it is used. `lapply` performs a funciton over each element in your list, and returns a list with the result of each.

Comment: I still get the same error when trying this though. Should I put this in the for loop?